# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation scale down my image

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I am using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate my button.But my button getting scaled(big or small) according to my value to rotate.How to stop scaling of my button? sample code i have used

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {
        self.btnMeter.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, (45 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0) 

    })
```

Comment: Where in the code you are making the transformation? In `viewDidLoad`? And, yes, post your code of transformation, please.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept my button on UIView.After that I have rotated my view using the same code.It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {
    btnMeter.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(btnMeter.transform, (45 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)

})
```

and put this in viewdidAppear instead of viewDidLoad